# Calculating confidence intervals for gamm4 models

Tags: r, confidence-interval, gamm4

I am working with gamm4 models in my research and am having trouble understanding how to go about calculating confidence intervals for my models.

EX model: m<-gamm4(turbidity~ year+discharge,data=data,random = ~(1|pool)) #where year is a factor and pool is a factor.

I would like to calculate the confidence interval of the model to appropriately present my results.

I have used se.ranef(m$mer)[["pool"]][,1] to get the standard error of the random effect, but am stuck on which value to use for the mean in calculating the confidence interval.

Is there a more efficient way to extract a CI from gamm4 models?

Comment: Usual gamma parameters are 'shape' and 'rate' or 'shape' and scale' (where scale is 1/rate). See Wikipedia page on "gamma dist'n" for parameter definitions, estimates, CIs. // I don't see how to match your stated parameters with the usual ones. // Gamma distn's are not symmetrical, so don't expect CIs to be of form param est $\pm$ marg of err (as for symmetrical normal and t distn's).

Comment: @BruceET Did the OP edit this? I'm not seeing what the Gamma distribution has to do with this model, which if the code is accurate (*big if*) is simply a linear mixed model.

Comment: Gamma model not sufficiently specified for discussion of exact Ci. More recent [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/580086/why-don-t-we-calculate-the-average-of-an-entire-given-population-instead-of-comp/580099#580099) briefly describes nonparametric bootstrap CI.